# One JavaScript function calling several others

Tags: javascript

I know that a javascript function is perfectly capable of calling other functions.  I've utilized this several times.

Currently I'm working on a script that will find the html elements of a certain tag, and add in a bit of text based on what kind of tag it is.

```
function foo() {
dealWithH1();
dealWithH2();           
dealWithH3();
etc...          
}
```

I have done a few searches regarding functions like this and what I can't seem to find is a definite, consistent answer to whether or not this is good practice.  I like this way, because there are a lot of function calls to make, and it keeps it very organized.  I just want to make sure before I get too far into it that there isn't some glaring problem with doing something like this.  The function `foo()` serves no purpose but to be called at `onLoad` and then call all of these other functions.

Is this okay, or is there a more encouraged way to get this done?

Comment: I'm not exactly an authoritative source on the matter, but in my opinion, if these functions `dealWithH1(); ...` are all of substantial size, this is just fine. It keeps your actual code more readable, since you can find what its purpose is.

Comment: Though, if `foo()` is the only thing you do onLoad, then it would be best to do away with `foo()`, and move the function calls into your onLoad call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable to create a pseudo-DSL of operations that are composed of functions.

Based on your description of what the `dealWith...` functions do, though, I think you might want to generalize your functions more, something like:

```
function foo() {
    tagInsert('h1', 'Text to append to h1 tag');
    tagInsert('h2', 'Text to append to h2 tag');
    tagInsert('h3', 'Text to append to h3 tag');
}
```

Now that the *essence* of the function has been distilled (append text to all tags of a specified type), and the variables of the function have been parameterized (the type of tag and the text to append), you could just as easily do something like:

```
var tags = {
    'h1': {
        'en': 'Hello',
        'es': 'Hola',
        'sr@latin': 'Zdravo'
    },
    'h2': {
        'en': 'Goodbye',
        'es': 'Adios',
        'sr@latin': 'Do vidjenja'
    },
    'h3': {
        'en': 'Green',
        'es'; 'Verde',
        'sr@latin': 'Zelena'
    }
};
function foo(locale) {
    for(var tag in tags) {
        tagInsert(tag, tags[tag][locale]);
    }
}
```

*Composability* of functions is greatly improved when as much about the operation you will perform is deferred until the function is actually called -- you can then use the exact same function to now not just append a fixed set of text to the tags, but to do so in whatever language the user prefers to use.

This flexibility can of course be taken to absurd lengths and you'd never get anything done, but it's good to think of your function as a set operator: what is the input to your function (declared explicitly as a variable or implicitly by accessing a global) and what operation is performed to produce the new output set?

If it doesn't take much extra effort to write the function in the generic way versus the specific case you're dealing with, then write it that way and you can re-use that function whenever you need to do a similar action but with different inputs.

#### Remember...

Don't take my `tagInsert` definition at face value, I know barely *anything* about what you're actually trying to do, and maybe that generalization doesn't really make sense. The point is that *you* as the developer should have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

If you follow [Larry Wall's Virtues of a Programmer](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer), you should be trying to minimize the amount of extra work you have to do, and your functions will reach the right degree of composability versus complexity.

Functions calling functions is the whole point of a function -- you avoid the need to rewrite it over and over again; just dividing a massive imperative declaration of actions to perform into a series of functions is *not* the point of a function. What are the repetitive patterns in the imperative code and how can you be as **lazy** as possible?

Comment: Was just writing something along the lines of your `var tags` approach when I saw this post. 

Let me add that depending on the context in which you're using this, you may want to call `tags.hasOwnProperty` for safety.

Comment: @user802500, that's certainly a detail that can matter when dealing with objects constructed with ``new``, but I left that out because JamesineBean seems confused about some of the fundamentals of programming, and a Javascript implementation detail would only cloud the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the code you wrote is not totally pseudo code, I will definitely don't do that: you will pollute the global scope with a lot of different functions. You could wrap those functions in a local scope using closure, or makes them methods of an object.

Also, it seems that `dealWithTagH1`, `dealWithTagH2` etc, have also the purpose to looking for these specific tags inside and modifying them. That's a logic you could extrapolate. So, you should have something that will get all the type of tags you're interested in, and then call the `dealWith` functions. In this way you have only one code that is looking for tags, and different function that deals with that specific tag. You decoupled more the logic in that way. If you want to put in an extreme way, you could have something like a Strategy Pattern.

I will modify the naming as well, gives to each "strategy" a better name (`dealWithTagH1` it's pretty generic, a developer that read that code doesn't have any hint about the actual strategy implemented).

Comment: I'd just like to note that 'polluting the global namespace' is just another option to weigh. Most of the time it's bad, especially when you're writing a library for others to use, but don't discount the usefulness of functions in the global scope; utility functions that perform generic actions on a large set of possible inputs are quite useful to have in the global scope so the rest of your code is easier to read. (``mergeObjects`` versus ``myLib.objects.merge`` for instance)

Comment: I made that sample pretty generic.  The function names will be much more meaningful once I settle on everything.

Comment: @JamesineBean that's why I start with "Assuming" :)

Comment: @DavidEllis I prefer in that scenario have CommonJS modules (with RequireJS on the browser) or similar kind of isolation. In that case I can get from the module I need the generic utility function. I have some modules for example called "utils/object" where I can get function like `merge` or `extend`, without pollute the global scope.

Comment: @ZER0 I'm glad you reminded me of things like that, though.  I started javascript only a couple days ago and I'm taking really small steps to get it working in the best way (or at least a way that won't make seasoned javascript programmers shake their heads in shame).

Comment: @ZER0, Sure, I use CommonJS modules all the time, but is that relevant to my point, and is pounding a newbie programmer such as JamesineBean with a dizzying array of Javascript-specific terminology a good idea? It's better for explanations to be general if the question itself is general, rather than the specific implentation details of a particular language and its runtime environment. Once he grasps the *actual concept*, the details of one implementation or the other will not confuse him.

Comment: @DavidEllis not sure I'm following you. Which JS-specific terminology I used in my answer to him? However, I don't see that as a big issue. If he want to be a JS developer, is better that is start to learn the terminology as well :)

Comment: @ZER0, well, perhaps I just write in too many languages, but Javascript-style closures don't exist in too many languages, and the scoping issue is particularly unique to Javascript in the browser, so I thought bringing that up, along with discussing OOP Patterns, distracted from JamesineBean's core problem of how functions help with code reuse; then your comments bringing up specific techniques to solve the scope issue (CommonJS modules) that has nothing to do with his problem just further pull your question *away* from actually answering him properly.

Comment: s/pull your question/pull your answer/

Comment: @DavidEllis mhm, I'm pretty sure that Python, Ruby, Smalltalk and Lisp have closures as well. And if I'm not wrong they are added to C# as well. Anyway, I didn't say "use closure!" and stop, I also propose an alternative ("or makes them methods of an object"), so I think it's more than reasonable. Said that, as I already wrote I don't see this as a big issue. If the original poster didn't know about closure, he could ask or searching: Stimulate curiosity is good! And have different opinions about how to deal with beginner or reply to a question is good as well. :) They both helps to grow!

Comment: @ZER0, well considering that Javascript counts Smalltalk and Scheme as direct conceptual "ancestors", and Ruby also counts Smalltalk as an "ancestor", it makes sense that other languages on that branch of languages also have closures. But *functions* are at almost the root of the evolutionary hierarchy of language design, and the issue JamesineBean had dealt with the operation of "pure" functions, not an issue caused by closures, so bringing them up seems off-topic. Furthermore, throwing a bunch of terminology around can just as easily scare off newbies, better to focus on one new concept.

Comment: @DavidEllis I got your point, I simple don't agree about what you say, and I think I expressed clearly why. I also think is perfectly normal have different opinions and how to answers to the users. :)

Comment: If I were to define an object and put those functions in as object methods, would those methods be able to see any of the variables that I need to keep global?

Comment: @JamesineBean definitely: global variables are, well, global. :)

Answer (score 2):

In virtually any mainstream language functions/methods are cheap and having as small and cohesive functions as possible is a good practice from maintenance and readability perspective. You should not fear creating functions, extracting them, calling them in hierarchy (one functions calls another one, which in turns calls third). You should also learn how to use [recursion](/questions/tagged/recursion).

Functions (including anonymous functions and closures) are the main building blocks in JavaScript and they are used everywhere, e.g. event handlers and callbacks.

Avoid functions longer than a screen (some say 10 lines, some 5 - just keep'em short). Also use functions to reduce duplication. For example something tells me that all your `dealWithH*()` are very similar. What about:

```
function foo() {
  dealWithTag('h1');
  dealWithTag('h2');           
  dealWithTag('h3');
  //etc...          
}
```

Of course in your case separate functions might be a better idea, but just think in terms of abstractions and try to generify the problem.